# Evaluation the function of a positive definite matrix

Tags: matrices

Consider the following function:

$f(K)= y^{T} K y-log(det(K)) $

Where $y \in R^n $ is a constant vector. $K$ is a positive definite matrix that has the properties:

(1). The main diagonal entries of $K$ are 1, i.e $K_{i,i}=1 ; \forall i=1,2,..,n$

(2). Every non-diagonal entries of $K$ are positive but less than 1. i.e $0<K_{ij}<1 ; \forall i \neq j$.

How can I find the maximum and the minimum of $f$ in this case ? I guess we need to figure out the derivative 
We have:
$$\frac{\partial f}{K}=yy^T -K^{-1} $$

So, if we want the derivative to be zero $K^{-1}=yy^T$ which is impossible, since $yy^T$ has rank 1. You can skip the constraint over the entries of $K$ for convenience.

Any thought is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to get an analytic answer, but you can formulate this question as a convex optimization problem, since $f(K)$ is convex as are your constraints.

$$
\mathrm{minimize}\,\,f(K)\\
\mathrm{subject\,\,to\,\,} K_{ii}=1, K_{ij} \in ]0,1[, K = K^T > 0
$$